# SSH server also runs OpenVPN client - Inbound SSH times out

Tags: ssh, openvpn, sshd

I've got a remote home server running Debian. I happen to use SSH on a non-standard port due to ISP blocking port 22. I've got no issues connecting to SSHd from outside of my network with the OpenVPN client not running on the server. The second I start OpenVPN client I get the following:

```
$ ssh -v -p 922 domain.dyndns.org
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.dyndns.org [1.2.3.4] port 922
debug1: connect to address 1.2.3.4 port 922: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host domain.dyndns.org port 922: Connection timed out
```

I have a dynamic IP address but the server is behind a router so I can't think to bind sshd to the public address. Even if it could, I'm not convinced the packets wouldn't get lost through the tun0.

On my travels of the Internet to try and resolve this issue, I found the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q fix_ssh /etc/init.d/openvpn || sed -i.backup -e '/start_vpn ()/ i fix_ssh () {\
ip rule add fwmark 65 table novpn\
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table novpn\
ip route flush cache\
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 922 -j MARK --set-mark 65\
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 922 -j DROP\
}\
undo_fix_ssh () {\
iptables -D INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 922 -j DROP\
iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 922 -j MARK --set-mark 65\
ip route del default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table novpn\
ip rule del fwmark 65 table novpn\
ip route flush cache\
}'\
   -e 's/start_vpn$/& \&\& fix_ssh/' \
   -e 's/stop_vpn$/& \&\& undo_fix_ssh/' \
/etc/init.d/openvpn
```

I've tried running it to no success. Comparing to other answers I've found, I'm not entirely sure where the issue lies with this solution and I've run out of ideas for troubleshooting.

I'm not entirely sure what the best approach to the issue is. The OpenVPN service is a commercial service I don't control.

Edit:
My goal is to be able to SSH into the SSH serve whilst it is running and connected to the OpenVPN server. I want all other traffic to go through the VPN. Eventually I want to use SSHFS to be able to view files on the SSH server and then port forwarding so my laptop miles away can share the same VPN connection.

`------------               ----------------
|My Server |--->OpenVPN>---|Commercial VPN |-->Internet>--Web
------------ Over internet |    Server     |
    |                      -----------------
   /|\
   SSH
Over Internet
   /|\
----------
| Laptop |
----------`

Edit 2: No, Laptop is in a different location to the SSHd server. Edited picture again for clarity.

Edit 3: There is a router involved. The server is behind a router. tun0 is the OpenVPN connection.

`$ sudo /sbin/iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Dec 26 13:03:22 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [11077726:5767595109]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9445198:5734927839]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10132207:7571233156]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10132784:7571256515]
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 922 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x41/0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 26 13:03:23 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Mon Dec 26 13:03:23 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9445173:5734925686]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10132201:7571259291]
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 922 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 26 13:03:23 2016`

Edit: Am I going to be better off having something like a Raspberry pi to ssh into to avoid this? Would I run into different difficulties? I'm still not sure of the root cause to know if this would resolve anything. Is a chain of SSH tunnels bad form? Idea being:

[Laptop]->SSH->--------->-[Pi]-Same Network->-[My Server]->-[OpenVPN]

```
              /|\                    
            [router]
```

Edit:

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.68.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.68.10.1      10.68.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 tun0
10.68.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.68.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.40.88.17    192.168.0.1   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0`

Contents of a .ovpn file:

`client
dev tun
proto udp
remote server 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass auth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.pem`

# Allow calling of built-in executables and user-defined scripts.
script-security 2

# Parses DHCP options from openvpn to update resolv.conf
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

Comment: Can you draw some ascii art of your setup, and can you tell us what you are trying to achieve? I think you have at least the following things, a `server` which is sometimes running the openvpn software and an ssh server on port 922. This sits on a LAN, which is connected to the world via a typical home router. This has a WAN address of domain.dyndns.org and forwards connections on port 922. There must be the endpoint of your openvpn connection somewhere, then you have the machine where you are running your `ssh -v -p 922` command, which network is it connected to?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does this mean that `Laptop` and `My Server` are on the same LAN (typically something like 192.168.1.x for a home machine)? All that this would seem to require is that the routing table on `My Sever` knows to send local traffic to the local lan rather than to the `Commercial VPN Server`.

Comment: Things are clearer now (pity there is no router in the diagram, unless `My Server` is directly exposed to the internet). Next we need your openvpn, routing and iptables configuration. Are you using `tun` or `tap` devices? Assuming TUN, the basic idea  is to set up NAT for all outgoing TCP packets except for ones with a source port of 922, with the NAT packets going down the OpenVPN connection.   Can you show us the output of `iptables-save` from the server with the openvpn connection enabled,

Comment: I suspect you've got a `redirect-gateway def1` in your OpenVPN configuration, which means that when the tunnel is active ALL traffic goes down the VPN connection - including attempts to reply to your inbound `ssh` requests. Please confirm the `redirect-gateway` element and we can continue from there.

Comment: @roaima How would I confirm that please?

Comment: Look in the OpenVPN configuration file. If you're following Debian's layout it'll be under `/etc/openvpn`. If you're not, it could be anywhere. Or it might be a default setting in NetworkManager. Another way to check is to be logged on the server when you start up the VPN and to run `netstat -rn`, putting the output into your question.

Comment: Ah. Somehow you are indeed getting the `redirect-gateway def1` set. The two lines in the routing table with a `Genmask` of `128.0.0.0` are the result of this setting, and they cause all traffic to be routed across the VPN.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this in the end?